# jQuery not working when adding code with a Wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I try simple code to see if jQuery is working. I use a WordPress plugin to add the code in the header section. I also tried to add the code to the body section.

However nothing changes (except the console log), and I wonder if something else is wrong.

example, I try to add a class to all Anchor elements:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    
    jQuery("a").addClass("test7");
console.log("code running");

});
```

I see the code in the page.
But why do I not see the added class to any anchor elements?
How should I test it?
I dont get any console error for this line of code.

Comment: So you don't see that class added to all anchor elements? Do you see the code in the page? We're not going to be able to help much with what you've shown us. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Yes I see the code in the page. But why do I not see the added class to any anchor elements?

Comment: Usually that means that the elements aren't present when the script runs. I'm not sure why that would happen on a WP site, though. Like I said, we can't really help with what we can't see.